# CodeIgniter - how to create a plugin system?

Tags: plugins, codeigniter-2

I want to develop a CI application that will allow me to create a number of classes and "magically" have those classes recognize by the application and be able to use them. For example, say I have plugins for animals and each class looks like this:

```
class Dog extends Animal
{
    public function get_description()
    {
        return 'A domesticated carnivorous mammal that typically has a long snout, an acute sense of smell, and a barking, howling, or whining voice.';
    }

    public function get_name()
    {
        return 'Dog';
    }

    public function make_sound()
    {
        return 'Bark, bark, bark!';
    }
}
```

Once this class is placed in some specified location, I want the application to be able to use it. Example uses would be:

1. List all the animal names and description
2. Make a specific animal do its sound
3. Etc.

Extensibility is my goal here. I want people to be able to extend this system by just developing additional classes for the application. Also, in reality, maybe each plugin may need more than just a class. Perhaps it may need CSS, JS, images, etc. Right now, I'm just trying to get the basic concept down so I'm just using a simple class as an example of a complete plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You can take sample:

CI-Plugin-System : https://github.com/Vheissu/CI-Plugin-System

Comment: does any bosy know how to use it .??

Comment: Firstly register methods with `add_action('sample.action', 'hello_world', 10)` plugin inside. After when you want to trigger this action, use `do_action('sample.action')`. Check out sample plugin file: https://github.com/Vheissu/CI-Plugin-System/blob/master/plugins/helloworld/helloworld.php